# How to calculate multiplication and percentage in user-form?

Tags: excel, vba

I need help with code for this form from image (quantity is amount!). When I press "calculate" to have a result in Textbox4 of price (Textbox2) for one piece at a discount (Textbox3), and at the same time result in Textbox4 of amount (Textbox1) multiplied by price (Textbox2) and discount (Textbox3).
like this:
`Textbox4 = Textbox3 (discount of) Textbox2`
and
`Textbox5 = Textbox1 * Textbox2  (with discount) Textbox3`

---

[image]

I have code for the first:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_AfterUpdate()
    With TextBox3
        .Text = format(Val(Replace(.Text, "%", vbNullString)) / 100, "#.0# %")
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    TextBox4.Text = Val(Replace(TextBox3.Text, "%", vbNullString)) / 100 * Val(TextBox2.Text)
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you clarify, are your values set for TextBox2 & 3 before you enter the quantity?  Why does that afterUpdate event have to happen?
If you enter the three top boxes and then click Caluculate.  Also, are you putting a "%" in the actual Textbox3?

Comment: I input the data in TextBoxes and press calculate, "afterUpdate" it was my fault and should be "Private Sub TextBox3_BeforeUpdate(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)"

Comment: But if you see I also have a problem when I enter in the textbox2 price and discount and textbox3?! I do not get what you need. For example, a 30% of 1000 is 700 but I get 300, how to be to be reversed?

Comment: 30% of 1000 is actually 300.  The discount is how much you are taking away and the price is the original price - the discount.

Comment: ok, my english is a little bad, but can you help me with the code and not with math?

Comment: What is the difference between TextBox2 and TextBox5?

Comment: [1 or 2 img](https://plus.google.com/u/0/116274910999260950523/posts/XBfFrmNuF7y?hl=sr&pid=6086832230028972514&oid=116274910999260950523)

Comment: in the textbox2 is price of one single piece, textbox5 is the Final price of textbox1, textbox2 and textbox3. This example of up comments with picture is the best explanation.

Comment: OK. thanks.  Although I will say you might want to consider leaving the % out of the text box since it's printed next to it anyway.  Thus eliminating having to remove it from the string every time you use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a little overboard with variables, but it's tested and works.  Having the variables declared from the textboxes, then using the variable names in the formulas makes it easier to see the actual math being done, instead of focusing on the data conversions.

Also as stated in the comment above, I'd not include the % in the textbox, but the Replace function does account for it.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim qty As Long         'Quantity
Dim discPct As Single    'Discount Percentage
Dim unitPrice As Single    'Single Normal Price
Dim discPrice As Single    'Single Price After Discount
Dim total As Single    'Total Qty * Discounted Single Price

qty = CSng(TextBox1.Text)
unitPrice = CSng(TextBox2.Text)
discPct = CSng(Replace(TextBox3.Text, "%", "")) / 100

discPrice = unitPrice - (discPct * unitPrice)
TextBox4.Value = discPrice

total = qty * discPrice
TextBox5.Value = total

End Sub
```

Comment: Something is wrong with "CLng converts", always is 0 and not, as in  my case for example 0.3. (of 30%) Theoretically is good and it should work, but... I do not know what's wrong!

Comment: I should have used Single Variable type for that, instead of Long.

Comment: You are brilliant well done !!! only if it is possible to add a comma to the right place, [Like this.](https://plus.google.com/u/0/116274910999260950523/posts/cG78HjqeSM5?hl=sr&pid=6087179111136081026&oid=116274910999260950523)

Comment: I'm glad you are able to get through it.  Make sure you are including the "/100" at the discPct.

Comment: Yes I includ the "/100", but never mind. I have another question why you Dim qty As Long and all other As Single?!

Comment: Single is more capable of dealing with decimals and more data.  Long is better for long whole numbers.  Since the qty will only be whole numbers you could use Long or Integer, but I think Long is more efficient on the computer.  Also, you would use that for counters, instead of Integer.

Comment: Thank you for your help and I learned a lot from this, and now I  extend this form on more options such as actuall percent * quantity and so on.... Thanks again and Bye!